# An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'WindowsApplication1.Form1.TextboxText().. same with labels

Tags: c#, static-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'WindowsApplication1.Form1.setTextboxText(int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-wi)

i am creating an IP tracer, which will connect to web and put value(IP) from textbox and will recieve the result. here is the code.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Xml;

    namespace geoIP
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                iptrace();
            }

             public static string iptrace()
            {
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlNodeList xmlnode;
                int i;

                xmldoc.Load("http://freegeoip.net/xml/" + textBox1.Text);
                xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("response");
                for (i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
                {
                    xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
                    label1.Text = "Ip Address: " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
                    label2.Text = "Country Code: " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim();
                    label3.Text = "Country Name: " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim();
                    label4.Text = "Region Code: " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerText.Trim();
                    label5.Text = "Region Name: " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(4).InnerText.Trim();
                    label6.Text = "City: " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(5).InnerText.Trim();
                    label7.Text = "Zip Code: " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(6).InnerText.Trim();
                    label8.Text = "Latitude: " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(7).InnerText.Trim();
                    label9.Text = "Longitude: " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(8).InnerText.Trim();
                    label10.Text = "Metro Code: " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(9).InnerText.Trim();
                }

            }


 }
}`
```

it giving me error

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'geoIP.Form1.textBox1'

Comment: Yes, it would give you that error. Now, how much do you understand about the differences between static and instance members, and return values?

Comment: Winforms is frequently the nemesis of a budding .NET programmer.  It is deceptively simple to make something work, the designer is very helpful to make something half-decent looking going quick.  Inevitably, you'll run into the wall of Object Oriented Programming, you *really* need to understand the difference between a type and an object to scale it.  Good books aplenty, certainly something you can learn in a school.  Not here.

Comment: How this has been upvoted 3 times is beyond my comprehension, it is basic knowledge

Answer (score 4):

your `textBox1` control is declared like a *member* of the class, but used inside `static` function. That is a problem.

To fix this, you need to declare method *non* `static`

```
public string iptrace()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: i removed it after that
public string iptrace()
{
   ...
}
it saying
'geoIP.Form1.iptrace()': not all code paths return a value

Comment: You defin your function with rturn type `string`, so return a string value  at the end. If you dont't need a string define function wih return type `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `static` from `iptrace()` method declaration.

You are trying to access non-static (instance) member `textBox1` from static method.

**Edit:**

Also, change the method declaration to `public void iptrace()`. Since you don't have `return <some string value>;` statement(s) (and you don't need any in your case), the C# compiler will object. By having [`void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) return type, you are stating that the method doesn't return any value.

**Edit 2:**

You should also change method access to `private void iptrace()`. No need for it to be public.

And finally, check [.NET Guidelines for Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx). For instance, methods and namespaces should be [Pascal Cased](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx).

Comment: i removed it after that public string iptrace() { ... } it saying 'geoIP.Form1.iptrace()': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Your method declaration is `public string iptrace() {...}`. You need to return a string value from it. But since you are just processing and don't expect anything returned, change the declaration to `public void iptrace() {...}`.

Comment: done, have you got any logical error in this source?

Comment: done, have you got any logical error in this source?

Comment: Added few more tips to the answer. Don't see any logical error.

Comment: then why its not showing result :(

Comment: @jammyhunt Do you get an error? Is the method iptrace() called at all? Check if the `button1_Click` event handler is correctly bound to `button1`'s `Click` event.

Comment: i found the bug :D
 xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("response");
it should be Response insted of responce

Answer (score 0):

Change `textBox1.Text` to be `Form1.ActiveForm.textBox1.Text`