# Palindrome - error

Tags: c#, palindrome

I'm quite new to C# and I was making a small application to check if the input of the console is a palindrome. I came pretty far by myself, but I got stuck with an error.

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str;
        Console.WriteLine("Voer uw woord in:");
        str = Console.ReadLine();

        if (isPalindroom(str) == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str + " is een palindroom");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str + " is geen palindroom");
        }

    }

    bool isPalindroom(String str)
    {
        string reversedString = "";
        for (int i = str.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            reversedString += str[i];
        }
        if (reversedString == str)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Error  1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication2.Program.isPalindroom(string)'    *snap*  17  17  ConsoleApplication2

Which is at:

```
if (isPalindroom(str) == true)
```

If you could help me a bit, I'd be very pleased :)

Comment: simply add `static` modifier to your isPalindroom method

Comment: @SteveB - post this as an answer - it IS the answer and you'll get we'll all up-vote you for it :)

Comment: You can't call non-static methods from static methods. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-wi

Comment: and please remove the `== true`.

Comment: Good luck as you learn C#!!!  Not the subject of your question (Someone beat me to that), but a few tips: There is an easier way to reverse the string with less code. http://www.dotnetperls.com/reverse-string  Also, in your if statement, you can eliminate "== true"  and just say `if (isPalindroom(str))`

Comment: and simplify the isPalindrom method : `return str == new string(str.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());`

Comment: `== true` is useless regarding the compilation (and I'm confident the compiler optimize this), but some people (not me) think this is more readable. I would say that we should let everyone decide whether or not it's useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `static` modifier to your `isPalindroom` method.

If you don't, `isPalindroom` will be an "instance" method, that can be called on a `Program` instance.

To be simple, as you don't have a variable of kind Program (main method itself is static), you can't call a non-static method.

A static method can be called either on the type itself (`Program.isPalydroom(xxx)` or from any other method in the class.

Comment: gosh, it's just that simple. Thanks for the explanation too. :)

Comment: It will be but i'm motivated ;)

Answer (score 3):

Make the function static:

```
static bool isPalindrome(String str)
{
}
```

The `Main()` method is static (by requirement) and thus it can only call static members.

And because your `bool isPalindrome()` is a 'pure' function, ie it only requires data from its parameters, it can be static.

Small nitpick: always use PascalCasing for method names, IsPalindrome

Answer (score 1):

Change 
    `bool isPalindroom(String str)`

to `static 
    bool isPalindroom(String str)`

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of "isPalindrome" needs to be modified to "static bool isPalindrome(String str)", or you need to put it in as a method of a class instance you can instantiate in Main and call from there.

Answer (score 1):

Main is static.. your function

```
  bool isPalindroom(String str)
```

should be

```
static  bool isPalindroom(String str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it;

```
static bool isPalindroom(String str)
{
 ....
}
```

The Main routine is static so you are not in an instance of the program class and cannot call an instance method. Making the isPalindroom a static routine will fix this.

For more on static methods and classes see;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned, you should make `isPalindroom()` method static.

Here a quick note about the way you're reversing the string:

Strings in C# are immutable, it means every time you're concatenating a new string (or character) to an existing one, it makes a whole new object. So to make the reverse routine more efficient, you may want to use `StringBuilder` and `StringBuilder.Append()`.

Aside from that, instead of:

```
string reversedString = "";
for (int i = str.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    reversedString += str[i];
}
```

you can simply type:

```
string reversedString = new string(str.Reverse().ToArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go, a better culture/case/normalization insensitive version

```
using System.Globalization;

bool IsPalindrome(string value, StringComparer comparer = null)
{
    if (s == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    }

    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
    }

    var elements = new List<string>();
    var m = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(value);
    while (m.MoveNext())
    {
        elements.Add(m.GetTextElement());
    }

    var i = 0;
    var j = elements.Count - 1;
    var limit = elements.Count / 2;
    for(; i <= limit; i++, j--)
    {
        if (!comparer.Equals(elements[i], elements[j]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```