# How do I fix this? An object reference is required for the non-static field - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm sorry for yet another stupid question. I am almost finished with my settings saving winform, with many thanks to the people of StackOverflow of course, but I am stuck on one final thing. Please don't mark this down just because I am a beginner.

I am getting the following errors:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ShovelShovel.WindowSize.Width.get'
>
> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ShovelShovel.WindowSize.Height.get'

Here:

Settings.cs

```
public partial class Settings : Form
{
    public Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var windowSize = new WindowSize { Width = WindowSize.Width, Height = WindowSize.Height };

        WindowSizeStorage.WriteSettings(windowSize);

        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Which goes to:

WindowSize.cs

```
public class WindowSize
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

public static class WindowSizeStorage
{
    public static string savePath = "WindowSize.dat";

    public static WindowSize ReadSettings()
    {
        var result = new WindowSize();
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
            {
                result.Width = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
                result.Height = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void WriteSettings(WindowSize toSave)
    {
        using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(savePath, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            binaryWriter.Write(toSave.Width);
            binaryWriter.Write(toSave.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?530631-I-m-having-trouble-with-my-code

There you can find the full files of my project in the attachments, in case the above is insufficient.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. Why all the code? Just show the line that causes the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-wi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you meant:

`var windowSize = new WindowSize { Width = this.Width, Height = this.Height };`

instead of:

`var windowSize = new WindowSize { Width = WindowSize.Width, Height = WindowSize.Height };`

As written, it would require Width and Height to be static properties of the `WindowSize` class, but I don't think that's what you intended.  Instead, it makes more sense to use the form instance `Width` and `Height` properties.

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed it. I will mark this as the answer when it will let me.