# usage of Dispatcher class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My code is as,

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
ping.PingCompleted += ping_PingCompleted;
ping.SendAsync(strTerminalName, 60, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sfk"));

 private void ping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
    Terminal.ChangeTerminalStatus(this.imgCurrent, TerminalStatus.UserOFF);
 }
```

Terminal has static method ChangeTerminalStatus which i am calling in that ping_PingCompleted.

**ERROR i got :-**

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it WPF.
```

Since i tried to change UI Property of a window in that statis method.

I searched and got solution to use  **Dispatcher.BeginInvoke** method.

When i tried to use this in a class which i has ping , Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
it throws error says

```
Error   2   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, params object[])'   D:\Net Projects\mercurial\icafemanager\ICMBusiness\Terminal.cs  124 17  ICM
```

Help me out in this.

Comment: it is not clear what is been asked. please rephrase.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'WindowsApplication1.Form1.setTextboxText(int)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-wi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BeginInvoke is not a static method of the Dispatcher class. You need a dispatcher *instance* to call it. In your tutorial, the class your were calling it from probably had a member that was named dispatcher, so it could be called as

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);
```

If you need the current Dispatcher, there is a static property [CurrentDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get it:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);
```

If your class already has a dispatcher object associated though, it's probably faster to use that.