# Call procedure within function

Tags: c#

Trying to call the procedure `cycles()` from within my function fibI, but the error is:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property                   array_calculator.Fibonacci_panel.cycles()'

Heres the procedure

```
      public void cycles()
      {
          k++;
      }
```

and the function

```
     public static double fibI(double input, int k)
     {
         if (input == 1 || input == 2)
         {
             return 1;
         }
         else
         {
             double fib1 = 0;
             double fib2 = 1;
             double fibResult = 0;
             for(double i = 1; i < input; i++ )
             {
                 fibResult = fib1 + fib2;
                 fib1 = fib2;
                 fib2 = fibResult;
                 cycles();
             }

             return fibResult; ;
         }
```

Comment: Maybe I simply can't see it, but what's the intension for "k"? I can't find any usages besides the "k++"

Comment: possible duplicate of [An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'WindowsApplication1.Form1.setTextboxText(int)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-wi) (and countless others)

Comment: k is used to count the number of times the cycle is ran- its for a school project

Answer (score 2):

Your "procedure" is not `static`. To repair you code just change:

```
public static void cycles() { k++; }
```

Moreover there isn't a "procedure" in C#. It is a normal function.

Comment: Note, `k` should be static variable also. But now question - what is passed to `fiBI`

Comment: +1. In all fairness, 'procedure' is a language-agnostic way to refer to any callable sub-program within a larger program.

Comment: uh it's called a method, not function or procedure

Comment: the function fibI used to work out the nth number in the fibonacci series. Our teacher said to do it like this as well as use recursion which works! We need to implement a counter to count how many cycles are needed to calculate the end value. I plan to call cycles() each cycle to count how many cycles there have been as i cant return it through the fucntion