# Object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Label1 Color change

Tags: c#

I have been trying to fix this for quite a while and I don't know if its my code or if it can't find it in VS.  I've literally tried everything and I need help

Error I get:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'WindowsFormsApplication3.Form1.label1'   c:\users\zmatar\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2013\projects\windowsformsapplication3\windowsformsapplication3\form1.cs

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void PingTest()
        {
            const int timeout = 120;
            const string data = "[012345678901234567890123456789]";
            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            PingReply reply;
            var success = true;    // Start out optimistic!
            var sender = new Ping();

            // Add as many hosts as you want to ping to this list
            var hosts = new List<string> { "www.google.com", "www.432446236236.com" };

            // Ping each host and set the success to false if any fail or there's an exception
            foreach (var host in hosts)
            {
                try
                {
                    reply = sender.Send(host, timeout, buffer);

                    if (reply == null || reply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        // We failed on this attempt - no need to try any others
                        success = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    success = false;
                }
            }

            if (success)
            {
                label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PingTest();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @TyCobb That would generate a slightly different error. "object reference required" errors are (nearly?) always issues relating to `static` things accessing instance things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'WindowsApplication1.Form1.setTextboxText(int)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-wi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label1` is a **instance** variable. You are trying to set it in a `static` method.

`static` methods cannot access instance members without an instance to go to. To fix it, remove `static` from the method, or store an instance of the class for use later:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
   static Form1 instance = null;

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       instance = this;
   }

   private static void MyMethod()
   {
      if (instance != null)
         instance.label1.Color = Color.White; //Or whatever
   }
}
```

Comment: `static Form1 instance = null;` ?

Comment: @Igor Yes, thank you for the catch on that. I have edited to fix.