# How do you access Ribbon controls (eg. RibbonEditBox) from outside class?

Tags: c#, ribbon, ribbonx

I have a Ribbon1 class which was created by the Visual Studio.

```
public Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonEditBox IDBox;
```

I would like to access one of the ribbon controls from within a different class.

```
using MyRibbon = ExcelAddIn1.Ribbon1;

xlTextID = MyRibbon.IDBox.Text;
```

I got the error message.

> An object reference is required for non-static field, method,
>   property.

I can't make IDBox static because it's initialized as an instance of a class via 'InitializeComponent()' method.

```
this.IDBox = this.Factory.CreateRibbonEditBox();
```

I have also tried to create a property.

```
    private Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonEditBox IDBox;

    public Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonEditBox IDBoxProperty
    {
        get { return IDBox; }
        set { IDBox = value; }
    }
```

Doing this I have seen exactly the same error.

How can I keep IDBox non-static and still access it from outside class?

I can found the answer - see it below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'WindowsApplication1.Form1.setTextboxText(int)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-wi)

Comment: As per many near-identical questions here on the "An object reference is required for non-static field, method, property", you are accessing the class as if it were an instance (object) of that class. Rather than `MyRibbon.IDBox.Text`, you need to create an instance of `MyRibbon.IDBox` (or, more like, access the exisiting instance created by the `InitializeComponent` method.

Comment: How do you access instances created by InitializeComponent method?

Comment: That completely depends on where you are trying to access it from.

Comment: I'm trying to access it from an external class. Ribbon1.cs lives in the main folder of the project. Then I have a folder called 'Controllers'. Inside this folder there is a class called 'Publishing'. I'm trying to access the Ribbon instance from within 'Publishing' class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances of the all Ribbon controls derived from `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon` can be accessed via `Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1`.

Therefore, in order to access `public Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonEditBox IDBox;` which is created by `InitializeComponent()`method, you would do `Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.IDBox`.

More information about accessing Ribbon Controls at Run-Time:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772088.aspx