# how to make an item static in an form

Tags: c#, .net, static

I have an listbox item in my form that is changed from an class that has to be static. Due to this, I tried putting the script into an different non-static class like this:

```
  private void addChat(string talk, string user)
   {
           console.Items.Add(user + ": " + talk);
   }
```

And is ran from here:

```
   static void OnMessage(object sender, PlayerIOClient.Message m)
    {
     //Code...
     string username = users[m.GetInt(0)]; //public static Dictionary<int, string> users = new Dictionary<int, string>();
     addChat(m.GetString(1), username);
     //More code...
    }
```

However I then get this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'NAME.Form1.addChat(string, string)'

Making this class static gives this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'NAME.Form1.console'

**How do I make the console (Which is a listbox) static?**

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-on). the link is probably your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. However, in general you could move your static logic to your static class and use it within your UI class.

**In your static class :**

```
private static string formatChat(string talk, string user)
{
   string.Format("{0} : {1}", user, talk);
}
```

**In your UI class:**

```
private void addChat(string talk, string use)
{
    console.Items.Add(formatChat(string talk, string use));
}
```