# Using the 'ref' keyword on an array

Tags: c#, arrays, ref

I understand why I should use `ref` when writing a function to swap two values, but I don't know how to use the keyword on an entire array. It sounds silly, but I have tried sticking the keyword everywhere I could possibly think of (e.g. before the parameter, before the variables, etc...) but I still get the following error:

> Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'Swap.Program.swapRotations(int[])'

Here is what I have done so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Swap
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

            swapRotations(A);

            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(A[i]);

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private void swapRotations(int[] intArray)
        {
            int bone1Rot = intArray[3];
            int bone2Rot = intArray[5];

            // Make the swap.
            int temp = bone1Rot;
            bone1Rot = bone2Rot;
            bone2Rot = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to fix compilation error: make `swapRotations` static too, because you call it from static method `Main`; and i don't understand what you are trying to do with `ref`

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with the `ref` keyword.  A static method can't call a non-static method directly, that's all.

Comment: If you search your error message on Google, I believe you would found your answer without asking here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property on a Windows form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-on)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple just change:

```
private void swapRotations(int[] intArray);
```

to:

```
private static void swapRotations(int[] intArray);
```

The problem is because the calling method is `static` so any method it uses either need to have an object referenced to them or be static themselves.

Also have a look at @ASh's answer on how to do the `swapRotations` function "properly". Note I say properly because there could still be an `IndexOutOfRange` exception thrown. To do this properly and genericly I'd do something along the lines of the following:

```
private static void SwapIndexes(int[] array, int index1, int index2)
{
    if (index1 >= array.Length || index2 >= array.Length)
        throw new Exception("At least one of the indexes is out of range of the array");

    int nTemp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = nTemp;
}
```

Comment: if you want to do it *properly* indeed, do not forget `index1<0` and `index2<0` cases; and *genericly* would be something along the lines: `void SwapIndexes<T>(T[] array, int index1, int index2) { T nTemp = array[index1]; array[index1] = array[index2]; array[index2] = nTemp; }`

Comment: @ASh I wasn't critising your method just showing **some** safety checks that can take place, anymore can be developed by the OP

Answer (score 2):

swap method doesn't work, because you don't change array at all

no need in `ref`, just set array elements

```
private void swapRotations(int[] intArray)
{
    int temp = intArray[3];
    intArray[3] = intArray[5];
    intArray[5] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Arrays` are `Reference` types. So there is no need to use `ref` keyword to pass an array. And your problem is not in `ref` keyword, but you **must** call only **static methods from static method**.
For example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

        swapRotations(A);

        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(A[i]);

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key ...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void swapRotations(int[] intArray)
    {           
        // Make the swap.
        int temp = intArray[3];  
        intArray[3] = intArray[5];
        intArray[5] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: Value/Reference types and pass by value/reference are _completely_ different subjects. That's not the point here