# in a C# script, i am getting object reference

Tags: c#, object, reference

How to clear the object reference is required error?
the script which i am using is coming up with the error that an object reference is required though i am trying to eliminating it by making it static but it isn't working out. can anyone please help me out?
do anyswer quickly because i have to finish up this project and move on.
[the image shows my script which is having the error object reference is required. can anyone help me clear that error please?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjH1X.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property on a Windows form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property-on)

Comment: *do anyswer quickly because i have to finish up this project and move on* == downvote and delete question as **quickly** as possible.

Comment: @Jim: I apologize it took so long to have me do the deed ;-)

Comment: @zx485 ;) no worries

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As indicated error message, `UDPCom.sendLTDimples` is non static function. So you will have to create a new object of class `UDPCom` and then using that object call the function.

```
UDPCom obj = new UDPCom();
Obj.sendLTDimples();
```

Comment: well thank you let me try it out :)

Comment: Why the down vote? Is the answer incorrect?

Comment: It's probably better to not answer such rude questions. It's better for the OP, since it would be an opportunity to learn from his misbehavior. Now, when he got an answer, he will most probably repeat his behavior next time, since he sees, that it's working for him.

Comment: sorry i have no clue why the down vote i haven't voted at all and dawid, bro there wasn't any misbehaviour from my side thanks

Comment: and @PratikGaikwad that vote is cast by someone else cause my votes arent shown

Comment: @MuhammadArsalanJaleesAbro if this helped you why don't you accept it as an answer?

Comment: honestly am new here so i don't really know how to but it really did help and thank you loads @PratikGaikwad