# How can I access a property that belongs to an instance of a class that I passed into another class?

Tags: c#

I have this class

```
public partial class PhrasesFrame : Frame
{

    public CancellationTokenSource tokenSource1;
    public PhrasesFrameViewModel vm;

    public PhrasesFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new PhrasesFrameViewModel(this);
    }
```

and this view model

```
public class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableProperty
{

    private readonly PhrasesFrame phrasesFrame;

    public PhrasesFrameViewModel(PhrasesFrame phrasesFrame) {
        this.phrasesFrame = phrasesFrame;
    }

    private void ResetTimer1()
    {
        if (phrasesFrame.tokenSource1 != null)

    }
```

on the `if` line where I use the value of `tokenSource2` I get a message saying:

Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PhrasesFrameViewModel.phrasesFrame'

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop)

Comment: The code you show compiles fine: https://ideone.com/G2sJ4L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the phrasesFrame’s variable in a static function. A static function can’t use a class’s non-static variable. Just remove the static
keyword and it will work.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the question as it was wrong. Can you look again.  Thanks