# Error with using ToString in ToString override

Tags: c#

I am new to coding and I have a problem with using `ToString` override. When I try to use already overloaded class's `ToString` in other `ToString` override, I get this error:

> An object reference is required to non static field, method, or property Freight.ToString()

Please help!

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace TruckCmopany
 {
     class Truck
     {
         private string name;
         private double weightCapacity;
         private List<Freight> freights;

         public Truck(string name,double weightCapacity)
         {
              this.Name = name;
              this.WeightCapacity = weightCapacity;
              List<Freight> freights = new List<Freight>();
         }

         public string Name
         {
             get { return name; }
             set { name = value; }
         }

         public double WeightCapacity
         {
             get { return weightCapacity; }
             set { weightCapacity = value; }
         }

         public override string ToString()
         {
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             sb.Append(this.Name).Append(" - ");

             if (freights.Count==0)
             {
                 sb.Append("Nothing loaded");
             }
             else
             {
                 sb.Append(string.Join(", ", freights)).Append(Freight.ToString());
             }

             return sb.ToString();
         }

         public IReadOnlyCollection<Freight> Freights
         {
             get => freights.AsReadOnly();
         }

         public void AddFreight(Freight freight)
         {
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Freight` is a class, not an instance of a class, what do you expect `Freight.ToString()` to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It's not a 'null reference' duplicate. The problem is that you call `Freight.ToString()` as a method on a static class, and confuse the compiler. It tries to resolve it to `object.ToString()` and fails.

Comment: You seem to not have properly grasped the concept of classes and instances of classes. You cannot call Freight.ToString() because Freight is a class and ToString is NOT a static method of the Freight class. You need an object reference to access non-static members of classes. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/498400/1800515

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop)

Comment: If your static class _really_ needs to have a static `.ToString`, mark it with `new public`, to explicitly hide the one inherited from `object`.

Comment: @DavidG  I am trying to use the ToString of another class in this one.I mean I overrided the ToString of class Freight and i want to add it to this one so i can print it like text

Comment: You can't **add** it to class Freight. I think you meant call or invoke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Freight.ToString()` is a call to a static method. It confuses the compiler, because it tries to resolve the call to the non-static `.ToString` inherited from `object`.

Since static classes cannot override members, if you *really* need a static `ToString` in your `Freight` class, you need to mark the method with `new public`.

---

Well, I see that your `Freight` is not a static class.

Then if I got you right, and you want a comma-separated string of freights, you need to simply do

```
sb.Append(string.Join(", ", freights));
```

It will call `.ToString` for each element implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to call `Freight.ToString()` ToString() has to be a static function, i.e., a function that belongs to the class itself that doesn't require any specific instance of the class to get invoked. However when you convert ToString to be static, you won't have access to the `this` modifier, since in a static method, there is no instance that you can refer to with `this`. So you are going to have to pass an instance of `Freight` to your static function.

You can then override ToString() and inside pass `this` to your static function. If you want to.

Read on Static Members: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members)

Read on Methods: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)