# c# an object reference is required for the non static field in main

Tags: c#

when attempting to debug this, even after asking help from friends and of  course google, i cant seem to debug this stupid  simple problem.

```
namespace BO2_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        #region Mem Functions & Defines
        [Flags]
        public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
        {
            All = 0x001F0FFF,
            Terminate = 0x00000001,
            CreateThread = 0x00000002,
            VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
            VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
            VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
            DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
            CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
            SetQuota = 0x00000100,
            SetInformation = 0x00000200,
            QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
            QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
            Synchronize = 0x00100000
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags processAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int processId);

        [Flags]
        public enum FreeType
        {
            Decommit = 0x4000,
            Release = 0x8000,
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum AllocationType
        {
            Commit = 0x1000,
            Reserve = 0x2000,
            Decommit = 0x4000,
            Release = 0x8000,
            Reset = 0x80000,
            Physical = 0x400000,
            TopDown = 0x100000,
            WriteWatch = 0x200000,
            LargePages = 0x20000000
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum MemoryProtection
        {
            Execute = 0x10,
            ExecuteRead = 0x20,
            ExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
            ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x80,
            NoAccess = 0x01,
            ReadOnly = 0x02,
            ReadWrite = 0x04,
            WriteCopy = 0x08,
            GuardModifierflag = 0x100,
            NoCacheModifierflag = 0x200,
            WriteCombineModifierflag = 0x400
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, AllocationType flAllocationType, MemoryProtection flProtect);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, int dwSize, FreeType dwFreeType);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, uint dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, out IntPtr lpThreadId);

        public byte[] cbuf_addtext_wrapper =
        {
        0x55,
        0x8B, 0xEC,
        0x83, 0xEC, 0x8,
        0xC7, 0x45, 0xF8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0xC7, 0x45, 0xFC, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0xFF, 0x75, 0xF8,
        0x6A, 0x0,
        0xFF, 0x55, 0xFC,
        0x83, 0xC4, 0x8,
        0x8B, 0xE5,
        0x5D,
        0xC3
        };
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
        IntPtr hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;
        int dwPID = -1;
        uint cbuf_address;
        uint nop_address;
        byte[] callbytes;
        IntPtr cbuf_addtext_alloc = IntPtr.Zero;
        byte[] commandbytes;
        IntPtr commandaddress;
        byte[] nopBytes = { 0x90, 0x90 };

        #endregion
        void Send(string command)
        {
            try
            {
                callbytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(cbuf_address);
                if (command == "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You must enter a command");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cbuf_addtext_alloc == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        cbuf_addtext_alloc = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)cbuf_addtext_wrapper.Length, AllocationType.Commit | AllocationType.Reserve, MemoryProtection.ExecuteReadWrite);
                        commandbytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
                        commandaddress = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)(commandbytes.Length), AllocationType.Commit | AllocationType.Reserve, MemoryProtection.ExecuteReadWrite);
                        int bytesWritten = 0;
                        int bytesWritten2 = commandbytes.Length;
                        WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, commandaddress, commandbytes, commandbytes.Length, out bytesWritten2);

                        Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(commandaddress.ToInt64()), 0, cbuf_addtext_wrapper, 9, 4);
                        Array.Copy(callbytes, 0, cbuf_addtext_wrapper, 16, 4);

                        WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, cbuf_addtext_alloc, cbuf_addtext_wrapper, cbuf_addtext_wrapper.Length, out bytesWritten);

                        IntPtr bytesOut;
                        CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, 0, cbuf_addtext_alloc, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out bytesOut);

                        if (cbuf_addtext_alloc != IntPtr.Zero && commandaddress != IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, cbuf_addtext_alloc, cbuf_addtext_wrapper.Length, FreeType.Release);
                            VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, commandaddress, cbuf_addtext_wrapper.Length, FreeType.Release);
                        }
                    }
                    cbuf_addtext_alloc = IntPtr.Zero;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        void FindGame()
        {
            if (Process.GetProcessesByName("t6mp").Length != 0)
            {
                cbuf_address = 0x5BDF70;
                nop_address = 0x8C90DA;
                dwPID = Process.GetProcessesByName("t6mp")[0].Id;
            }
            else
            {
                cbuf_address = 0x0;
                nop_address = 0x0;
                Console.WriteLine("No game found.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            hProcess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, dwPID);
            int nopBytesLength = nopBytes.Length;
            WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (IntPtr)nop_address, nopBytes, nopBytes.Length, out nopBytesLength);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cmd;
            for (; ; )
            {
                FindGame();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a command: ");
                cmd = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(cmd + " is now being executed");
                Send(cmd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

of course i cant make the void not static. what would you suggest i do?
as you can see, it is pulling from the regular voids.

Comment: Please elaborate the problem with more details and proper full example.

Comment: what is `Send`, what is `FindGame`

Comment: Also `for (; ; )` this is extremely ugly... just saying

Comment: I suspect `FindGame` and/or `Send` are not `static`

Comment: @MickyD Just updated with the full code

Comment: @TheGeneral i use that to create a  loop

Comment: @JaydeepJadav updated

Comment: Then use a `while(true)` instead of `for ( ; ;)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make them static

```
static IntPtr hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;

static int dwPID = -1;

static uint cbuf_address;

static uint nop_address;

static byte[] callbytes;

static IntPtr cbuf_addtext_alloc = IntPtr.Zero;

static byte[] commandbytes;

static IntPtr commandaddress;

static byte[] nopBytes = { 0x90, 0x90 };

private static void Send(string command)

private static void FindGame()
```

Basically, you cant call instance members from a static context which is what `Main` is

You will need to either

- Make a new class and instantiate it and put everything in there
- or make everything else static