# How can I access label.Text from my User Control

Tags: c#

I want to access labelNummer.Text from my User Control in my form.

Form

```
if (idPartijen.Contains(labelNummer.Text))
        {
            con.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM `kandidaat` where `partijnummer` =@nummer ");
            con.Cmd.Parameters.Add("@nummer", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = labelNummer.Text;
```

User Control

```
  public string KandidaatNummer
    {
        set
        {
            Nummer = value;
            labelNummer.Text = Nummer;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UserControl

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string KandidaatNummer
    {
        get
        {
            return labelNummer.Text;
        }

        set
        {
            labelNummer.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say that your user control has a name called: MyUserControl1

```
 if (idPartijen.Contains(myUserControl1.KandidaatNummer)) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed my code but now it gives me the error an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Please check if this is the case on your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop