# SPWeb.GetFolder Unable to Pass String Value In

Tags: c#, sharepoint, spweb

I am unable to pass a string value into my `SPWeb.GetFolder` despite my input being a `string` value.

```
private static void UploadEmlToSp(string sharePointSite, string sharePointDocLib, string emlFullPath, string requestNo)
{
    using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite))
    {
        using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(emlFullPath))
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", emlFullPath);

            SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[sharePointDocLib];

            if (SPWeb.GetFolder(requestNo).Exists) <--errored
            {
                //Folder Exisits
            }
```

May I know what have I missed?
Below is the error message.

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property SPWeb.GetFolder(string)`

Comment: my `requestNo` is a parameter that is parsed in from my `main`. do I need to specially handle it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop)

Comment: sorry, this one might be a duplicate. [`SPWeb.GetFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb?view=sharepoint-server) is not indicated as a static and you call it on a static method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling an *instance* method like a *static* method. Just use the instance of `SPWeb` you have in `oWeb`

```
if (oWeb.GetFolder(requestNo).Exists)
```

---

[Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Answer (score 0):

Use the instance of the object oWeb that you created to get the method. The code should be written as follows

```
 if (oWeb.GetFolder(requestNo).Exists){
         //Folder Exisits
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

SPWeb.GetFolder is not a staic method as official document specific:

[SPWeb.GetFolder Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getfolder?view=sharepoint-server)

So use the instace oWeb instead:

```
oWeb.GetFolder(requestNo).Exists
```