# How to make a sprite slower when it moves over a sprite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object called "Player" and my map is made up of short grasses and long grasses. If my player is on the long grass, I want it to slow down. One additional problem is that there are multiple Long grasses game objects in my game. Here is a screenshot of them :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSxvf.jpg

This is what my current movement code looks like :

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Sprite Up;
    public Sprite Down;
    public Sprite Right;
    public Sprite Left;
    public float speed;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Vector3 move;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Up;
            move = new Vector2(0, speed * Time.deltaTime);

            transform.position += move;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Left;
            move = new Vector2(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

            transform.position -= move;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Right;
            move = new Vector2(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

            transform.position += move;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Down;
            move = new Vector2(0,speed * Time.deltaTime);

            transform.position -= move;
        }
    }
}

// All my code does is that on each WASD, it changes to a different sprite and moves it.
```

An explanation would be appreciated because I'm a beginner to this.

Comment: just by logic, if collision detection is found, slow the sprite?

Comment: Yes but I don't know how I'd go about doing that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use colliders, eg. boxcolliders to detect if player is touching the grass.
2. Use a tag on you player
3. use the oncollisionenter2d() method on the grass

> ```
>  void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)  {
>      if(col.tag == "PlayerTag") {
>          playerScriptWhereSpeedIsLocated.speed = 1 //the speed you want
>      } }
> ```

Comment: @HSN720 Seems like i answered your question, the error you are now getting is another problem, you should read up about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop

If you do get the code to work, would you mind marking the question answered?

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this would be to use [2D Trigger Colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-isTrigger.html).

Assuming your player has some sort of 2D collider attached to it, you may attach trigger colliders to your grass objects which can then send a message to the PlayerMovement script when the player enters/leaves the trigger by adding the [OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) and [OnTriggerExit2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit2D.html) methods to your PlayerMovement class. Here's an example of how this might work:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    // You can use gameObject.tag to determine what type of object we're colliding with
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "LongGrass"){
        speed = .8f;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "LongGrass"){
        speed = 1f;
    }
}
```

I would encourage you to look into the [Collision action matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) if you are having 
trouble detecting collisions in this way. You'll also make sure you tag your grass correctly for this method to work.