# C# Error calling async Task with arguments from Main

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, httprequest

This is my method, an async HTTP POST :

```
public async Task CreateConsentAsync(Uri HTTPaddress, cHeaders cconsHeaders, cBody ccons, HttpMethod Method)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true);

        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, HTTPaddress))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = HTTPaddress;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SomeHeader", cconsHeaders.SomeHeader);
            //etc..

            request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ccons, Formatting.Indented), utf8, "application/json");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                Int32 code = (Int32)response.StatusCode;
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error in " + e.TargetSite + "\r\n" + e.Message); Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When I try to call it from Main, supplying all arguments correctly, like:

```
CreateConsentAsync(NewConsent.BaseURL, NewConsent.Headers, NewConsent.Body, HttpMethod.Post).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I get error:

> An object is required for the non-static field, method or property
>   'Program.CreateConsentAsync(Uri, cHeaders, cBody, HttpMethod)'

Any ideas and help would be much appreciated..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop)

Comment: Thank you #Selvin it helped, but is another issue as well there.

Answer (score 1):

The method `CreateConsentAsync` is an instance method and hence not a static method. If you want to call it as the error message you shared, you should mark it as a static one:

```
public static async Task CreateConsentAsync
```

Comment: Hi Christos, thank you; it worked. However: in another namespace, I did a class, say, ClassA and inside I did blabla mynew = new blabla (I have done the dependency between two projects) and then I tried to find mynew.CreateConsentAsync and doesn't appear in Intellisense; produces error. If however you feel it can be done, please share a snipet, I'm really stuck with this...
Thank you for the correction !

Comment: @Nick Hi, you are welcome. Could you please share the code you say that you have problem with, by updating your post ? Thanks !