# An object reference is required for a non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, console-application, dll-injection

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Threading;
using EasyExploits;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        EasyExploits.Module module = new EasyExploits.Module();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Module.LaunchExploit();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Label:
            Console.WriteLine("Please Type 'Inject'");
            string proccess1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (proccess1 == "Inject")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Injected!");
                goto Begin;
            }
            else
            {
                goto Label;
            }
            Begin:
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a script and press enter to execute it.");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            Module.ExecuteScript(answer);
            goto Begin





        }
    }
}
```

So, I tried finding a solution to this problem but I could not find one so I came to stack overflow. Anyway, my Console Application is supposed to Inject the EasyExploits.DLL and Execute a Lua script when a script is pasted into the input. However, I am getting and error saying, **"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Module.LaunchExploit()'"** and **"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Module.ExecuteScript(string)'"** I am a beginner to c# and do not really understand this error so if someone could walk me through it with easy steps that are beginner friendly that would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop)

Comment: EasyExploits.Module module = new EasyExploits.Module(); needs to be in the Main() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Main` method is static and you can access **only** static members of the same class from a static method. All you need to do to make your `EasyExploits.Module` static as well:

```
private static readonly EasyExploits.Module module = new EasyExploits.Module();
```

Comment: And after that use that member `module` instead of the class `Module`. I.e. `module.LaunchExploit();` instead of `Module.LaunchExploit();`

Comment: Same applies to `ExecuteScript`

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues here

1. Module is a class, but `LaunchExploit()` is not static, that is, it needs to run from an `object`. You probably meant to use the object `module`
2. `module` should be `static` as well, if you want to use it inside a `static` function `main`

I would also mention a less pressing issue: `goto` are rarely a good idea. Your code can become nicer if you:

1. Create a static function `begin`, and wherever you have `go to Begin` do:

```
begin()
return;
```

2. Create a `static` function `label`, do the same for it

This will make your code much more readable and debuggable.