# I'm writing a Function called WriteSlow() and it gives me a error. how do i fix it?

Tags: c#

I want to write a small function but it gives a error:
Error CS0120    An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Program.WriteSlow(string, int)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Dank_meemr
{
    class Program
    {
        int wordLength;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteSlow("Hello World!", 10);
        }
        public void WriteSlow(string text, int delay)
        {
            
            wordLength = text.Length;
            Console.Write(text[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(text[0 + 1]);
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

How do you fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop)

Comment: Just add `static` keyword to your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and events in their containing type.

You will need to make your method static

```
public static void WriteSlow(string text, int delay)
```

---

[Compiler Error CS0120](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120)

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or
> property 'member'
>
> In order to use a non-static field, method, or property, you must
> first create an object instance. For more information about static
> methods, see Static Classes and Static Class Members. For more
> information about creating instances of classes, see Instance
> Constructors.

---

**Additional Resources**

[Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)