# HI! I am a newbie to C#, can someone please help me out with this code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to open a form inside a panel by clicking btnPlaceOrder which is on the same panel

```
 private void btnPlaceOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmDashboard.PanelDesktop.Controls.Clear();
        frmPlaceOrder formPlaceOrder = new frmPlaceOrder();
        formPlaceOrder.TopLevel = false;
        frmDashboard.PanelDesktop.Controls.Add(formPlaceOrder);
        formPlaceOrder.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        formPlaceOrder.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        formPlaceOrder.Show();
    }
```

error im getting:

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'frmDashboard.PanelDesktop'   projectRMS  E:\projectRMS\projectRMS\frmOrders.cs   28  Active

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you didn't instantiate frmDashboard

```
frmDashBoard frmDashboard= new frmDashBoard();
```

Comment: `frmDashboard`, with a lowercase B, is the name of the type.