# ItemEvent in SAP B1 SDK with a SAP form created in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, event-handling, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I truly really need your help.

I want to be able to deal with a Click on an Item on my Form which has been created in Visual Studio 2015

this is my Main Methode :

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Application oApp = null;
            if (args.Length < 1)
            {
                oApp = new Application();
            }
            else
            {
                oApp = new Application(args[0]);
            }
            Menu MyMenu = new Menu();
            MyMenu.AddMenuItems();
            oApp.RegisterMenuEventHandler(MyMenu.SBO_Application_MenuEvent);
            
            
            Application.SBO_Application.AppEvent += new SAPbouiCOM._IApplicationEvents_AppEventEventHandler(SBO_Application_AppEvent);
          
   
            oApp.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
        }
    }
```

and this code is automatically generated by Visual studio when i creat a new SAP B1 Project.

now i want to add an ItemEvent to handle some klick events on some Forms.

when i add this to the code :

```
Application.SBO_Application.ItemEvent += new SAPbouiCOM._IApplicationEvents_ItemEventEventHandler(SBO_Application_ItemEvent);
```

und of course the Methode SBO_Application_ItemEvent then i got a compiler error in this code line that an object reference is requiered for non-static fields...

what did i miss?

I just want to be able to do something when the User clicks on the Grid in my Form.

Comment: what is the code for your SBO_Application_ItemEvent ?

Comment: private void SBO_Application_ItemEvent(string FormUID, ref SAPbouiCOM.ItemEvent pVal, out bool BubbleEvent)
        {} simple Methode lets Say.

Comment: does this help ?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/498410/8504824

Comment: unfortunately not! The problem is that i need to know how to do it with the SDK SAP B1 which has some kind of another Syntax and also Symatic and this is what i somehow dont understand in this Problem. But Thank you anywas :)

Comment: are you using the form designer in visual studio ?

Comment: Yes but the project is a SAP Business One Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Method to add a click event to a grid on a custom user form,
using Visual Studio and SAP BUSINESS ONE STUDIO:

1. Open the .b1f file in visual studio designer.

an example form:
[image: an example form:]

2. Click on the Grid you wish to add the event for and navigate to the properties window
3. Click the lightening symbol to see the events
   [image: Add Event To Grid]
4. Double click the space next to your Desired Event

visual studio should then add the code for the event as required, something similar to the below should appear in code:

```
private void docRowGrid_ClickBefore(object sboObject, SAPbouiCOM.SBOItemEventArg 
pVal, ref bool BubbleEvent)
{
}
```

Comment: but as i see you are the one who could answer my next question. When someone clicks on my Grid i get a path where a file is saved. its like \\sap01\archive\filename.pdf. now i want to open this file after clicking on it. can you help me with that?

Comment: no problem :)  try:   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\sap01\archive\filename.pdf")

Comment: ** you are the best** That woked perfectly! you bring it directly to the point. Do not you like to give online lessons? :)