# WCF Web Service / Visual Studio Community 2022 / Compiler Error CS0120

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, visual-studio-2022

I want to access a web page in a Windows Forms app via SOAP.

Unfortunately, the compiler spits out many errors after I added the WCF Web Service to the project. What am I doing wrong here? The possible options don't tell me anything. The examples I found on the Internet could not help me with the errors.

Visual Studio Community 2022

WCF Web Service
URI: https://www.onlinembe.de/wsdl/OnlineMbeSOAP.wsdl

[ ] Always generate message contracts
[X] Reuse types in referece assemblies

- [X] Reuse types in all referenced assemblies

Access level for generated classes:
[X] Public

Compiler Error CS0120
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property "ShipmentRequestType.System".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop)

Comment: [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120) from the official documentation may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'Reference.cs' add 'using System.Xml.Schema;'
and replace
'Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified'
with
Form='XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified'.

Comment: It worked. How did you find the solution?

Comment: I saw a conflict between the names of the web service (SystemType System) and the namespace System.Xml.Schema.